# The product of 2 independent markov chains

Tags: probability, independence, markov-process

Let $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ and $(Y_n)_{n≥0}$ be two independent Discrete-time Markov chains $\in Z$.

a) Define the process $Z_n = (X_n, Y_n)$ $\in Z^2$. Is $(Z_n)_{n≥0}$ a Markov chain?

b) Define the process $W_n = X_nY_n$ $\in Z$. Is $(W_n)_{n≥0}$ a Markov chain?

For a) I've got $$ P[Z_n=k | Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1}, Z_{n-2}=z_{n-2},...,Z_0=z_0] = P[Xn=k_x, Yn=k_y | X_{n-1}=z_{n-1_{x}}, Y_{n-1}=z_{n-1_{y}},..., X_{0}=z_{0_{x}}, Y_{0}=z_{0_{y}}] = \text{(due to the independence of {Xi} and {Yj} and Markov property for Xn and Yn}) = P[X_n=k_x | X_{n-1}=z_{n-1_{x}},Y_{n-1}=z_{n-1_{y}}]P[Y_n=k_y | Y_{n-1}=z_{n-1_{y}}, X_{n-1}=z_{n-1_{x}}] = P[Z_n=k|Z_{n-1}=z_{n-1}] $$ - so $(Z_n)$ is a Markov chain. Is my reasoning correct?

For b) I have no idea.

Comment: What operation on random variables does "$*$" signify in part (b)?

Comment: @whuber Just a simple product, probably I shouldn't have typed it

Comment: Thanks.  (Sometimes the star is used for a convolution and represents the *sum* of random variables.)

Comment: cross-posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317544/the-product-of-2-independent-markov-chains

Answer (score 1):

For a, your answer looks fine.

For b, you need to think about possible factorization from the primes of `XY`.

Let's say `XY = 12`, for all pairs of X and Y whose product is 12, namely, 1 and 12, 2 and 6, 3 and 4, the process is still memoryless. This is the result in part a, stating all possible pairing retains memorylessness.

Comment: You mean the answer is yes? And to prove it i should use the following idea: let  {$a_i$, $b_i$} ($i \in 1,...,m$) be all ($m$) possible pairs of integers such that $a_ib_i=k$. Thus
$$ P[W_n=k | W_{n-1}=w_{n-1}, W_{n-2}=w_{n-2},...,W_0=w_0] = P[X_nY_n=k | X_{n-1}Y_{n-1} = w_{n-1},...,X_0Y_0=w_0] = P[(X_n=a_1, Y_n=b_1) U ... U (X_n=a_m, Y_n=b_m) | X_{n-1}Y_{n-1} = w_{n-1},...,X_0Y_0=w_0] = P[X_n=a_1, Y_n=b_1 | X_{n-1}Y_{n-1} = w_{n-1},...,X_0Y_0=w_0] + ... + P[X_n=a_m, Y_n=b_m | X_{n-1}Y_{n-1} = w_{n-1},...,X_0Y_0=w_0] $$
But what should I do next? How can i use that ${Z_n}$ is Markov?

Comment: I can do the same decomposition for $w_{n-1},...,w_0$ : $w_i = c_{i_j} d_{i_j}$ for $j \in 1,...,m_i$ and get something like 
$$P[X_n=a_1, Y_n=b_1 | ((X_{n-1}=c_{{n-1}_1}, Y_{n-1} = d_{{n-1}_1}) U...U (X_{n-1}=c_{{n-1}_{m_{n-1}}}, Y_{n-1} = d_{{n-1}_{m_{n-1}}})), ((X_{n-2} = ...) U ... U (..)),..., ((X_0 = c_{0_1}, Y_0=d_{0_1}) U... U (X_0 = c_{0_{m_0}}, Y_0 = d_{0_{m_0}}))]$$ If I didn't have union in the conditional part it would be easy (I would just use the Markov property for $(X_n, Y_n)$, so how should I deal with these unions?